# Server Creation "Localhost" not working in node JS

Tags: node.js, proxy, localhost

i'm new to NodeJS programming and i'm trying to do some basics exercises with VSCode.
The first exercise i'm trying to do is the **server creation**, but i get the classical error "this site can't be reached". So, i can't get into my "localhost:3000".
The code i'm pretty sure it's correct (attached below) since it's a copy-paste taken from a learning website.
My issue i think it's in the computer settings. I tried to switch on/off the proxy but nothing changed.
Can please anybody help me? I'm stuck at the very beginning :(

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write('<h1>Hello Node!!!!</h1>\n');
  response.end();
}).listen(3000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try running it on a different port:

Comment: PS: i've also tried to go to: control panel-->programs-->turn windows features on or off-->turn on "internet information services" and "internet information services HWC". I tried this setting with proxy on and off, nothing changed.

Comment: var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write('<h1>Hello Node!!!!</h1>\n');
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080');

Comment: I am running it on linux and it works as is and also after changing the ports to 8080 from 3000

Comment: already did it, tryied several ports: 8080, 5000... none of them works. Think the porblem it's in the PC settings

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with the port, please kill the port and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `writeHead()` is not complete. It is better to use something like:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

This way the browser knows that you are sending a HTML document.

Comment: Hi, you meant:  'restart.writeHead...' ?   Anyway it's not working yet. The problem is in the pc settings, but i don't know which ones.